# highlight image when clicked on then check a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

You know those sites that have an image as a checkbox and which ever image is checked gets highlighted? I'm trying to do the same, but instead with a radio button and I can't seem to get it to work. Here's my code:

**html**

```
<div class="well">
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <label class="image-radio">
                  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&txt=100%C3%97100&w=100&h=100" />
                  <input type="radio" name="style" value="option1" />
                  <div class="item-detail">Trim & Cutt <div class="item-price">$55.00</div></div>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <label class="image-radio">
                  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&txt=100%C3%97100&w=100&h=100" />
                  <input type="radio" name="style" value="option2" />
                  <div class="item-detail">Trim & Cutt <div class="item-price">$55.00</div></div>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <label class="image-radio">
                  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&txt=100%C3%97100&w=100&h=100" />
                  <input type="radio" name="style" value="option3" />
                  <div class="item-detail">Trim & Cutt <div class="item-price">$55.00</div></div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.image-radio {
  cursor:pointer;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  border:4px solid transparent;
  outline:0;
}

.image-radio input[type="radio"] {
  display:none;
}

.image-radio-checked {
  border-color:#f58723;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display:none;
}

.item-detail .item-price {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#201E20;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        // init the state from the input
        $(".image-radio").each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('input[type="radio"]').first().attr("checked")) {
                $(this).addClass('image-radio-checked');
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass('image-radio-checked');
            }
        });

        // sync the state to the input
        $(".image-radio").on("click", function (e) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('image-radio-checked')) {
                $(this).removeClass('image-radio-checked');
                $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').first().removeAttr("checked");
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass('image-radio-checked');
                $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').first().attr("checked", "checked");
            }

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dwc6gf4q/5/

Comment: always check the developer console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have to use the radio buttons? If not, just keep the state in the script like you already do. When you click an image change the state to active and check the other images for being active. If one is, set it to inactive.
Then, if you need the radio buttons, you can change their state with the same function.

EDIT: Fiddled a little: https://jsfiddle.net/dwc6gf4q/41/

As far as i understood, works like you wanted.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
        // init the state from the input

        // sync the state to the input
        $(".image-radio").on("click", function (e) {
          $(".image-radio-checked").each(function(i){
              $(this).removeClass("image-radio-checked");
            });
     $(this).toggleClass("image-radio-checked");
            e.preventDefault();
            
        });
    });
```

```css
.image-radio {
  cursor:pointer;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  border:4px solid transparent;
  outline:0;
}

.image-radio input[type="radio"] {
  display:none;
}

.image-radio-checked {
  border: 4px solid #f58723;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display:none;
}

.item-detail .item-price {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#201E20;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well">
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <label class="image-radio">
                  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&txt=100%C3%97100&w=100&h=100" />
                  <input type="radio" name="style" value="option1" />
                  <div class="item-detail">Trim & Cutt <div class="item-price">$55.00</div></div>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <label class="image-radio">
                  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&txt=100%C3%97100&w=100&h=100" />
                  <input type="radio" name="style" value="option2" />
                  <div class="item-detail">Trim & Cutt <div class="item-price">$55.00</div></div>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <label class="image-radio">
                  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&txt=100%C3%97100&w=100&h=100" />
                  <input type="radio" name="style" value="option3" />
                  <div class="item-detail">Trim & Cutt <div class="item-price">$55.00</div></div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how would i write it for radio buttons tho? i have to use radio buttons for what im trying to do.

Comment: sweet thanks!!.  i modified it to work with checking and unhecking the radio buttons within code. https://jsfiddle.net/sarmenb/dwc6gf4q/43/

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be working to me. You had some js errors because you weren't adding jquery to the fiddle...try here: https://jsfiddle.net/dwc6gf4q/6/

```
added jquery to fiddle
```

Comment: thanks, but what im trying to do is have only one of them checked at a time since their radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this using CSS just need to put IMG code after the radio button.

```css
.image-radio {
  cursor:pointer;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  border:4px solid transparent;
  outline:0;
}

.image-radio input[type="radio"] {
 visibility:hidden;
}

.image-radio img {display:none;}
.image-radio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ img {display:block;}
.image-radio-checked {
  border-color:#f58723;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display:none;
}

.item-detail .item-price {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#201E20;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="well">
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <label class="image-radio">
                 
                  <input type="radio" name="style" value="option1" />
                 <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&txt=100%C3%97100&w=100&h=100" />
                  <div class="item-detail">Trim & Cutt <div class="item-price">$55.00</div></div>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <label class="image-radio">
                  
                  <input type="radio" name="style" value="option2" />
                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&txt=100%C3%97100&w=100&h=100" />
                  <div class="item-detail">Trim & Cutt <div class="item-price">$55.00</div></div>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <label class="image-radio">
                  
                  <input type="radio" name="style" value="option3" />
                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&txt=100%C3%97100&w=100&h=100" />
                  <div class="item-detail">Trim & Cutt <div class="item-price">$55.00</div></div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```